# How to run a spatial query with a raster and vector layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, query

I have a soil map (vector-polygon layer) and a map of the crops farmed in the same area (raster layer, from the US Cropland Data Layer).

I would like to calculate for a given soil type, the surface farmed per crop. How do I do that?

The Zonal Statistics and ZonalStats plugins didn't solve my problem.

Hope I am clear enough. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Raster to Polygon tool in QGIS's Raster menu.  Then you can run an intersection to get a cropland / soil layer.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to write your own custom script .. Following link will be good resource for you 
http://planet.qgis.org/planet/user/3/tag/quantum%20gis/

Comment: How would this custom script work? What functions, specifically, do you suggest to use?

Comment: Thanks! Could you give more details about the script you think I should write? I confess I don't know where to start.